# Pandas: Generate Experiment Results in Adjacency-Like Matrix Table

Tags: pandas, matrix

I have a set of experimental results (anonymised subset below) in dataframe format read from a CSV file ('Input.csv'). I want to output a table comprising the columns - 'Experimenter', 'Subject', 'F', and 'G' - in an adjacency-matrix-like format. It should include aggregating by average for multiple entries - for example, 'Alpha' and 'Bravo' - in reciprocal roles as 'Experimenter' and 'Subject'. In addition, there should be '1.00's along the main diagonal. Finally, the final output table should be written to a CSV file ('Output.csv').

Actual Input:

```
Day,Experimenter,Subject,D,E,F,G
Monday,Alpha,Bravo,4,2,2.68,0.44
Monday,Charlie,Delta,0,2,0.62,2.29
Monday,Echo,Foxtrot,1,2,1.03,3.14
Monday,Golf,Hotel,1,2,0.75,2.53
Tuesday,India,Juliet,2,1,0.71,1.60
Wednesday,Foxtrot,Charlie,2,0,0.48,0.61
Thursday,Delta,Hotel,2,3,2.06,1.93
Thursday,Bravo,Alpha,1,1,0.53,0.41
Friday,Bravo,Delta,1,1,1.65,0.84
Friday,Golf,Alpha,0,0,0.19,1.30
Friday,India,Echo,1,0,1.31,0.58
```

Expected Output:

```
        Alpha   Bravo   Charlie Delta   Echo    Foxtrot Golf    Hotel   India   Juliet
Alpha   1.00    1.39    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.30    0.00    0.00    0.00
Bravo   0.485   1.00    0.00    1.65    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
Charlie 0.00    0.00    1.00    0.62    0.00    0.61    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
Delta   0.00    0.84    2.29    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    2.06    0.00    0.00
Echo    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    1.03    0.00    0.00    0.58    0.00
Foxtrot 0.00    0.00    0.48    0.00    3.14    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
Golf    0.19    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.75    0.00    0.00
Hotel   0.00    0.00    0.00    1.93    0.00    0.00    2.53    1.00    0.00    0.00
India   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.31    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.71
Juliet  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.60    1.00
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Friday'],
                    'Experimenter': ['Alpha', 'Charlie', 'Echo', 'Golf', 'India', 'Foxtrot', 'Delta', 'Bravo', 'Bravo', 'Golf', 'India'],
                    'Subject': ['Bravo', 'Delta', 'Foxtrot', 'Hotel', 'Juliet', 'Charlie', 'Hotel', 'Alpha', 'Delta', 'Alpha', 'Echo'],
                    'D': [4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                    'E': [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                    'F': [2.68, 0.62, 1.03, 0.75, 0.71, 0.48, 2.06, 0.53, 1.65, 0.19, 1.31],
                    'G': [0.44, 2.29, 3.14, 2.53, 1.60, 0.61, 1.93, 0.41, 0.84, 1.30, 0.58]})

adjacency_matrix = pd.crosstab(df['Experimenter'], df['Subject'], values=df['F'], aggfunc=np.mean)
adjacency_matrix = adjacency_matrix.fillna(0)

print('')
print(adjacency_matrix)
```

Actual Output:

```
Subject       Alpha  Bravo  Charlie  Delta  Echo  Foxtrot  Hotel  Juliet
Experimenter                                                            
Alpha          0.00   2.68     0.00   0.00  0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
Bravo          0.53   0.00     0.00   1.65  0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
Charlie        0.00   0.00     0.00   0.62  0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
Delta          0.00   0.00     0.00   0.00  0.00     0.00   2.06    0.00
Echo           0.00   0.00     0.00   0.00  0.00     1.03   0.00    0.00
Foxtrot        0.00   0.00     0.48   0.00  0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00
Golf           0.19   0.00     0.00   0.00  0.00     0.00   0.75    0.00
India          0.00   0.00     0.00   0.00  1.31     0.00   0.00    0.71
```

which is correct but only includes column 'F' not both 'F' and 'G', as required.

Please advise?

Comment: Hi, in your actual output, for Bravo>Alpha, wouldn't you expect `(0.53+1.65)/2` instead of `0.53`? Also, in the expected output, for Bravo>Alpha, how do you calculate `0.485`?

Comment: @Laurent. Thanks for the follow-up. I have just posted some code that generates the required output, which is functional but not very idiomatic. I continue to struggle to generate some centrality measures. If you can help with with the former or the latter or both, that would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code appears to generate the correct output (not very idiomatic, but functional):

```
ct_a = pd.crosstab(df['Experimenter'], df['Subject'], values=df['F'], aggfunc=np.mean).fillna(0)
ct_a.values[[np.arange(ct_a.shape[0])]*2] = 1
print('')
print(ct_a.head(23))

ct_b = pd.crosstab(df['Subject'], df['Experimenter'], values=df['G'], aggfunc=np.mean).fillna(0)
ct_b.values[[np.arange(ct_b.shape[0])]*2] = 1
print('')
print(ct_b.head(23))

a_m = (ct_a + ct_b).fillna(0)
a_m.values[[np.arange(a_m.shape[0])]*2] = 1
print('')
print(a_m.head(23))
```

However, I am still struggling to generate the **'Eigenvector Centrality'** measure from the generated matrix (a_m) - any help would be very welcome!

Comment: Hi, it seems you have answered your initial question (although your code only outputs matrix of '1'?), you should mark is as such and post a new question in regard to the 'Eigenvector Centrality' measure. Also, you should fix the expected output in your question. Cheers.